# Introducing a delay for updating the post preview box

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview, editor

When typing up or editing a question the completed version is shown in the box below. When editing this means that the whole text is constantly being refreshed which is just plain annoying. Would it be possible to introduce a delay (maybe 7 seconds) between output box refreshments?

Comment: Somewhat related feature request on meta.se: [Allow me to disable preview while answering in MathJax enabled sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253011).

Comment: It's more a problem with plain text than equations because you know exactly what the text will come out like, so the constant updating of the post preview box is just an annoying distraction. I take it the downvoter disagrees with this.

Comment: White the meta.SE feature request was certainly centred around MathJax and how disruptive constantly updating that can be, I think that it is unlikely that such a feature would be introduced _only_ on MathJax-enabled sites. (Also, if implemented, it doesn't really matter _why_ you hide the preview.) I do find it odd that you can hide the preview when editing, but not when asking/answering.

Comment: How do you hide it while editing?

Comment: When editing a post there is a "hide preview" button/link [below the editor box on the left-hand-side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UVTRB.png).

Comment: It ain't there. I'm using Chrome so I'll just blame google. Makes a change from blaming microsoft.

Comment: It doesn't appear when you are "suggesting edits" (_i.e._, when editing while having <2K reputation).

Comment: But it doesn't appear when I'm editing my own questions either!

Comment: Good suggestion, I don't know why it was downvoted. I think 7 seconds might be too long though. I think the most "natural" delay would be when you pause typing. This can probably be empirically figured out, but I'd imagine a delay of half a second or even less would do the job. It would definitely make things a bit smoother. Also would be nice to have the maths smoothly change appearance rather than go to plaintext and then back again.

Comment: [robjohn has some very useful bookmarklets](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), notably one to enable/disable mathjax rendering. I find it's the most annoying thing about the constant re-rendering, in addition to consuming an enormous amount of CPU time and making me able to cook eggs on my laptop.